# How do I return a struct as json using fiber in golang?

Tags: go

Since I couldn't find any tutorial on internet about this simple problem, I must write here to get help.

I have this function:

```
package main

import (
    "encoding/json"

    "github.com/gofiber/fiber/v2"
)


type Person struct {
    email string
}

func main() {
    app := fiber.New()

    app.Get("/", func(c *fiber.Ctx) error {
        user := Person{
            email: "mikolaj73@gmail.com",
        }

        u, err := json.Marshal(user);

        if err != nil {
            panic(err)
        }

        return c.JSON(u);
    })

    app.Listen(":5000")
}
```

But when I visit 127.0.0.1:5000, it says: "e30=" instead of the user json. How do I do it?

Comment: The program JSON encodes the JSON encoding of `user`.  Encode once with `return c.JSON(user)`.  Also, [export](https://go.dev/ref/spec#Exported_identifiers) the fields in Person.  `type Person struct {  Email string }`.

Comment: "e30="is base64 of "{}",c.JSON Encode it

Answer (score 2):

As others have shared, `fiber.Ctx.JSON` does the marshaling for you. Calling `json.Marshall` beforehand means you are marshaling twice. Just drop that off.

You actually need to use `c.JSON` here. Do not manually marshal and return as string.

`fiber.Ctx.SendString` responds incorrectly with header "Content-Type: text/plain" while `fiber.Ctx.JSON` responds correctly with "Content-Type: application/json" (expected behavior in both cases).

Answer (score 1):

See this

> type Person struct {
> Email string
> }

Your member of struct must be uppercase,then json.Marshal will work

Change

> return c.JSON(u)

To

> return c.SendString(string(u))

If Using c.JSON It Will Turn Your String Be Base64 format

```
package main

import (
    "encoding/json"

    "github.com/gofiber/fiber/v2"
    "fmt"
)


type Person struct {
    Email string
}

func main() {
    app := fiber.New()

    app.Get("/", func(c *fiber.Ctx) error {
        user := Person{
            Email: "mikolaj73@gmail.com",
        }
        fmt.Println(user)
        u, err := json.Marshal(user);

        if err != nil {
            panic(err)
        }
        fmt.Println(u)
        fmt.Println(string(u))
        return c.SendString(string(u))
    })

    app.Listen(":5000")
}
```

Always Using Println Or Something To Debug Before Complete Full Project